# How to edit option keys value in Gloudemans/Shoppingcart for laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using [this](https://packagist.org/packages/gloudemans/shoppingcart) package in order to use shopping cart in my project. 
When I'm adding some data to cart im using following code. and its working fine.

```
Cart::instance(session('email'))->add($part_number.$variation,$part_number,$quantity,$price,
            ['capa' => $variation, 'from'=>$from, 'ship_via' => $item->shipping_method,'code'=>$code,'paint_price'=>$paint_price, 'shipping_price' => $shipping_price]);
```

Initially when I'm adding an item shipping_price will be 0, in Checkout page, I want to manipulate this ***shipping_price*** key. but this following code is not working.

```
Cart::instance(session('email'))->update($row_id,['shipping_price' => $shipping_price]);
```

However when I want to edit the ***price*** key of the cart like this:

```
  Cart::instance(session('email'))->update($row_id,['price' => $cart->qty * $cart->price + $shipping_price]);
```

its totally working fine. So basically I want to edit the ***shipping_price*** which is in the options array of that Cart's Content(). Anyone who worked with Gloudemen, any kind of help is appreciated.

Comment: think could be there a solution without use that framework or anything like that, just using pure php you an do that

Comment: I can do that , but I don't want use pure php to manipulate carts data as it might follows other dependency. ( as it is a framework ) custom manipulation might give error in some extent.

Comment: you cant add extra parameter but u can add as many u want in ur options array. add 0 valued element  while create the cart later update it

Answer (score 1):

I hope is better:

```
$item = Cart::get($rowId);
$option = $item->option->merge(['color' => 'red', 'size' => 'XL']);
Cart::update($rowId, ['qty' => 60, 'price' => 299, 'options' => $option]);
```